# Baker Clamp application for PNP Transistor

Tags: bjt, pnp, switching-losses

I have an issue related to Baker Clamp application for PNP Transistor. I know how to implement the Baker Clamp for NPN Transistor. However I do not know how to do it for PNP. So could anyone can suggest me a schematic?

Secondly, can the Baker Clamp reduce the turn-off time of PNP transistor?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: to convert NPN to PNP just reverse everything. (all voltages, all diodes etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this one?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGXdrt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Standard 2 diode version of a Baker Clamped NPN transistor on the left.

Switch all the arrows round, and viola, the PNP version on the right.

Omit D1/D3 and replace D2/D4 by shottky or germanium for the one transistor version. This is the normal way the technique is used today.

Add another diode anti-parallel to D1/D3 for the 3 diode version. This is faster than the two diode version, as the extra diode provides a path for base charge to be abstracted by the driving circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7aSeD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The clamp will speed up switch off of a PNP, as it prevents collector saturation and so excess charge storage.

Answer (score 2):

The  Baker clamp uses carefully selected Schottky to raise Vce >Vce(sat) and Silicon diodes to raise Vce(max) and to lower BC pF somewhat like a Schottky Transistor used in 74Sxx and 74LSxx but at the expense of Pd drop like a Darlington.  This raises the VI product while also raising the transition frequency.

Most recent IC to use this I know is here.   http://home.mira.net/~gnb/audio/lme49810.html

It is important to realize when rCE drops to conduct more current, the equivalent Collector capacitance  Cce and storage charge increases which is an RC=T (approx. limitation) . The same is true in cascading power FETs with T=RonCoss and RgCiss so there becomes an optimal critical ratio of Ron/Rg for fastest yet efficient speeds .  In slow SMPS it is common to see Ron/Rg be 1000:1 where in fastest high power FET designs this sometimes reduces to 10:1 in Ron  Input driver/Output driver ratios.

This is also apparently true in optimized   Baker designs where the Ic/Id has been suggested around 4:1 which to me implies a  component power ratio of each.

Perhaps as well just as ESR*Pd(max) =1 is somewhat a design constant in all  diodes with some reduction from 1 to 1/2 due to improved SMT thermal design and some rising to 1.5 due to poor bulk resistance which accounts for all the tolerance spreading of Vf/If at rated current tolerances often to +-50%.

I realize this is more than you asked for,  but I thought others may find useful. If not voted as useful, I may reduce my answers in future. (Typing on an iPod is hard,with frequent incorrect spelling subs. but then I can be resting on the beach!)