# PNP transistor interface is not switching PWM inputs with low duty cycles

Tags: pwm, pnp, duty-cycle

The following transistor circuit section(using a PNP transistor [BC557B](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/fairchild%20semiconductor_bc559-320188.pdf)) is inverting and buffering a 25kHz PWM pulse train coming from one of the Nano's PWM supported digital pins. The following is the schematics diagram in LTspice:

[image]

As you see above, 25kHz PWM signal with 300ns ON time works fine in simulation.

In practice I tested this on a breadboard:
[image]

It looks a bit messy but it is exactly the same circuit. The 5V for the PNP transistor comes from Nano's +5V supply pin. I guess it supports up to 500mA or even some more.

So when I set the PWM to 25kHz and the ON time to around 300ns and when I probe the PWM output right before R4 the scope shows the following:
[image]

**But** at the output(probing between R3 and GND) the output is constant 5V as:
(Sorry for the blur photo)
[image]

So the PNP obviously does not turn ON at this duty cycle unlike in simualtion.

Then I gradually increased the ON time of the PWM and it started to switch barely fine when the ON time was 1.5μs. Here is the scope screen for this at R4:

[image]

And below shows the output(at R3):
[image]

I tried to lower the values of both R4 and R3 down to 330 Ohm. But it didnt make any difference.

What could be the limiting the switching behavior of the transistor at low duty cycles here? Is the transistor not fast enough? What could be a remedy to lower this limit?

**EDIT:**

I found [this](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/13fe/0900766b813fed0f.pdf) PMOS and its SPICE model in a site as:

```
.model TP2104 PMOS (LEVEL=3 RS=0.73 NSUB=5.0E14 DELTA=0.1 KAPPA=0.0411 TPG=-1 CGDO=6.1716E-10 RD=1.91 VTO=-2.10 VMAX=3.0E6 ETA=0.12098 NFS=3.384E11 TOX=1.0E-7 LD=1.6980E-9 UO=865.45 XJ=6.5E-7 THETA=4.063E-5 CGSO=9.10E-9 L=2.5E-6 W=0.5E-2)
```

Then for a 10ns pulse(10 MegHz) input I compared the outputs in simulation for the BC557B and [TP2104](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/mosfets/8793270/). Below shows the plots:

[image]

At least in simulation this particular PMOS worked better. But I didn't try it on breadboard yet.

Comment: Show a graph with the input to the PNP and the output.

Comment: What is the propagation delay between input and output?  As in post a scope shot of input **AND** output as @laptop2d says.  Odds are your transistor is not fast enough.  You may need a MOSFET.

Comment: Or you may be having Cout issues on the port with large current drives, but changing the resistance should have changed that.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Why does it matter the thing is under 1500ns the transistor does not switch at all. I showed adl those in the question. I dont have access to it at the moment so I dont know the prop delay.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Please see my edit. I tried a particular small signal PMOS for high speed switching applications. In simulation it gave much better results comparing to the PNP BC557B.

Comment: At 150MHz max clock rate (6.7ns), 1.5μs pulse should trigger transistor.

Comment: In your circuit (pnp version). You made a wrong assumption and assumed that " PNP obviously does not turn ON" . Witch is not the case here. The opposite is true. The PNP transistor do not have enough time to leave the saturation region due to the "storage time". More  you can find here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/367750/emitter-follower-power-stage-of-an-amplifier-with-switch-off-capacitor/367975#367975 and here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/358517/baker-clamp-application-for-pnp-transistor

Comment: https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/transistor-in-active-and-saturation-region.159013/page-2#post-1384678